# facing recaptcha has already been rendered this element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I was trying to add firebase phone otp verification on a project but getting frustrated by the message of recatcha has already been rendered on this element ,on a first try the otp sends successfully to the mobile number and goes to verified page but whenever I try to navigate to the otp send page again using back arrow key of the browser gives that recaptcha rendered error I thought on return If I clear the recaptchaVerifier It will be fixed but it did not solve the problem

Code:

```
typeexport default function testPage() {
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const router = useRouter();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const checkboxRef = useRef(null);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!window.recaptchaVerifier){
      const auth = getAuth(app);
      try {
        // Check if reCAPTCHA has already been rendered
          window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "sendCode", {
            size: "invisible",
            callback: async function (recaptchaToken) {
              // reCAPTCHA solved, send recaptchaToken and phone number to backend.
              const phoneNumber = inputRef.current.value;
              console.log(recaptchaToken);
  
              try {
                await signInWithPhoneNumber(
                  auth,
                  phoneNumber,
                  window.recaptchaVerifier
                );
  
                console.log("OTP sent successfully");
                router.push("/verified");
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error signing in:", error);
              }
            },
          });
  
          // Render the reCAPTCHAVerifier.
          window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function (widgetId) {
            window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;
          });
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating/re-rendering reCAPTCHA verifier:", error);
      }
  
      return () => {
        // Clear the reCAPTCHAVerifier only if it has been rendered
        if (window.recaptchaWidgetId) {
          console.log("Clearing reCAPTCHA verifier");
          try {
            window.recaptchaVerifier.clear();
            window.recaptchaVerifier = null; // Reset the verifier
            window.recaptchaWidgetId = null; // Reset the widgetId
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error clearing reCAPTCHA verifier:", error);
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }, []); // Add 'app' to the dependency array if it's not declared in the code you provided
  

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        color: "black",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <input id="isSignup" ref={checkboxRef} type="checkbox" />
        <label for="isSignup">isSignup</label>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
        <button id="sendCode"> send otp </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried to search on the google about the solution but did not get fixable solution